# I want to paginate through a table using selenium in java

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests

I need your help I want to paginate through a table an store the values of it untill "Next Button" disables.
Although storing values is not ossible its ok. But help me in pagination I want to click on the button it the next button untill it is  not disabled .Please help me. I am on a internship

Java Code:

```
package Onsight.Framework;

import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

import com.github.javafaker.Faker;

import avdhut.onsight.commonutils.BaseComponenets;
import avdhut.onsight.pageobject.HomePage;
import avdhut.onsight.pageobject.LoginPage;
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;

public class Webtable extends BaseComponenets {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        String urlString = "https://oinsightsvm1.westindia.cloudapp.azure.com:444/ctsOInsightsBMS/res/createReport.html";
        String userEmailString = "User66";
        String userPassword = "Avdhut@5201";
        String titleString;
        String textString="Clarita";
        Faker faker = new Faker();
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        // options.addArguments("--ignore-ssl- errors=yes");
        options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.get(urlString);
        LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
        loginPage.login_username(userEmailString);
        loginPage.click0nsubmit();
        loginPage.EnterPassword(userPassword);
        loginPage.click0nsubmit();
        HomePage homePage = new HomePage(driver);
//      homePage.view_report_values(textString);
        IsVisible(baseTableBy);
        WebElement baseTable=driver.findElement(baseTableBy);
        List<WebElement> table_roWebElement=baseTable.findElements(report_name_rowsBy);
        for (WebElement webElement : table_roWebElement) {
            if (webElement.getText().contains(report_title)) {
                System.out.println(true);
                IsClickable(viewBy);
                System.out.println(webElement.getText());
                webElement.findElement(viewBy).click();
                IsClickable(view_dataBy);
                driver.findElement(view_dataBy).click();
                while (IsVisible(paginateBy)) {
                    IsClickable(paginateBy);
                    driver.findElement(paginateBy).click();
                }
                
                
            } else {
                
            }
    
    }
}
//tr[class='odd'] em[class='fa fa-table']
```

Html:

[image]

Comment: Post the URL, post the correct code (we cannot debug this code, because you copied this code from a framework, create a standalone file, execute the code then post that code), and explain your issue clearly.

Comment: @AbiSaran I have updated the file. I want to paginate through the table untill the the last page . In updated code I have accheived it partially. But it gives me an exception "thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document". Please help me. Apologies for late reply as I was sleeping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After logging in, once you reach the table which contains the list of reports, add the below code and try:

```
Thread.sleep(2000);
            
// to close the toast message, if the toast message does not appear, comment the below line         
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//button[@class='toast-close-button']")).click();
            
boolean flag = true;
// below while loop will click the 'NEXT' button until it is disabled
while (flag) {
    WebElement nextBtn = driver.findElement(By.id("query-table_next"));
    if (!nextBtn.getAttribute("class").contains("disabled")) {
        nextBtn.click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } else {
        flag = false;
        System.out.println("In the last page");
    }
}
```